# Split a column with a number and name into two different columns 'ID' and 'Name'

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting a text file to csv.
In the csv file Im getting a column having a number and name in it (e.g 1: Aki ) , I want to seperate them both in two different columns.

samle data

```
1: Aki 
2: Aki
3: Kano
```

code tried

```
df_output.columns = ['Name', 'date', 'Description']

###df_output['ID'],df_output['Name_'] = df_output['Name'].str[:1],df_output['Name'].str[1:]

obj = df_output['Name']
obj = obj.str.strip()
obj = obj.str.split(':/s*')
df_output['Name'] = obj.str[-1]
df_output['idx'] = obj.str[0]
df_output = df_output.set_index('idx')
```

Comment: `:/s*` you have a forward slash instead of a backslash. Your regex should be `r":\s*"`.

Comment: Do none of the answers in this post work in your case?

Comment: yes they worked, Thank you...and the main mistake i made was...I was using ':' instead of '：' which was entered using a Japanese keyboard so the regex was not matching the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.extract` here:

```py
df_output['ID'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'^(\d+)')
df_output['name'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'^\d+: (.*)$')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, just need to change some of the syntax. Try this:

#### create data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column": ["1: Aki", "2: Aki", "3: Kano"]})

print(df)
    column
0   1: Aki
1   2: Aki
2  3: Kano
```

#### clean data

Let's remove whitespace, then split our column on `": "` (colon followed by space)

```
clean_df = (df["column"].str.strip()                     # remove whitespace
            .str.split(": ", expand=True)                # new df with 2 columns (0, 1)
            .rename(columns={0: "number", 1: "name"}))   # new df renamed columns

print(clean_df)
  number  name
0      1   Aki
1      2   Aki
2      3  Kano
```

#### combine cleaned data with original

Now that our data is nice and clean, we can `join` it back to the original dataframe:

```
final_df = df.join(clean_df)

print(final_df)
    column number  name
0   1: Aki      1   Aki
1   2: Aki      2   Aki
2  3: Kano      3  Kano
```

#### All together

```
final_df = df.join(
            df["column"].str.strip()
            .str.split(": ", expand=True)
            .rename(columns={0: "number", 1: "name"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

After fixing your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['1: Aki','2: Aki','3: Kano']})

df = df['Name'].str.split(r':\s*',expand = True).rename({0:'idx',1:'Name'},axis =1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  idx  Name
0   1   Aki
1   2   Aki
2   3  Kano
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# add sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['1: Aki','2: Aki','3: Kano']}) 
   
df[['idx','Name']] = df.Name.str.split(":",expand=True) 
   
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **extractall** method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["1: Aki", "2: Aki", "3: Kano"]})

df = df.col.str.extractall(r"(?P<id>\d+):\s*(?P<name>\w+)").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    id  name
0   1   Aki
1   2   Aki
2   3   Kano
```